# Printing current frame in flash using Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, frame

Hey I'm putting together a timed quiz game through flash and I'm trying to set a code that  will allow users to print the content from the frame which they are currently on. (i.e. - if they wanted to print their progress at 5 minutes or on question 20, etc..). I've been able to bring up the print options box but every time I click OK to print it comes out blank. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);

function onPrintClick(event:Event):void{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.printing.PrintJob;

    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
    var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    if (!printJob.start()) {
        return;
        printJob.addPage(mySprite); 
        printJob.send();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few immediate issues with your code. Hopefully sorting them out will solve your problem.

Firstly, you should put your `import` statements at the very top of your code.

Secondly, for `if(!printJob.start())` you're saying if the print job hasn't started do this

```
return;
printJob.addPage(mySprite);
printJob.send();
```

That will mean that `printJob.addPage(mySprite)` & `printJob.send()` will never get called.

Thirdly, if you are using that `Sprite` object straight from `new Sprite()` then it is blank anyway. Try drawing a red square and then printing.

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
// now print
```

Is that any help?

Comment: If you want to print the screen try

    printJob.addPage(stage);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response!

Okay so I made the adjustments to the code which you had suggested.. Definitely fixed the problem of it printing blank (now there's a red box in the top left hand corner), but I'm still trying to figure out how to turn the current frame into a sprite on printing so that all of the text and images of that frame print instead of the red box..

Here's my updated code:

import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.printing.PrintJob;

print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);

function onPrintClick(event:Event):void{

```
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    mySprite.graphics.endFill();

    printJob.start(); 
    printJob.addPage(mySprite); 
    printJob.send();
```

}

This is making me crazy!! Haha.. Any further advice would be much appreciated!..

Thanks!